# Error 126 Thumbnail not working on mediawiki and imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, mediawiki, thumbnails

Underneath you see an errorlog from an upload of the picture Delano_Hutjens.jpg
And it is not a problem to upload, but when the script is converting it to an thumbnail I got the error:

> Error creating thumbnail: sh: /usr/local/bin/: Is a directory Error
>   code: 126

Any idea where I can search for a solution?

```
[thumbnail] thumbnail failed on vserver247.axc.nl: error 126 "sh: /usr/local/bin/: Is a directory" from "'/usr/local/bin/' '-quality' '80' '-background' 'white' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/public_html/naslag/images/7/74/Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '-thumbnail' '143x239!' '-set' 'comment' 'File source: http://aanbevolen.nu/naslag/index.php/File:Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '+set' 'Thumb::URI' '-depth' '8' '-sharpen' '0x0.4' '-rotate' '-0' '-sampling-factor' '2x2,1x1,1x1' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_f297587e6fc2.jpg'"
[thumbnail] Removing bad 0-byte thumbnail "/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_f297587e6fc2.jpg". unlink() succeeded
[thumbnail] thumbnail failed on vserver247.axc.nl: error 126 "sh: /usr/local/bin/: Is a directory" from "'/usr/local/bin/' '-quality' '80' '-background' 'white' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/public_html/naslag/images/7/74/Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '-thumbnail' '358x599!' '-set' 'comment' 'File source: http://aanbevolen.nu/naslag/index.php/File:Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '+set' 'Thumb::URI' '-depth' '8' '-sharpen' '0x0.4' '-rotate' '-0' '-sampling-factor' '2x2,1x1,1x1' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_bcaab4a27945.jpg'"
[thumbnail] Removing bad 0-byte thumbnail "/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_bcaab4a27945.jpg". unlink() succeeded
[thumbnail] thumbnail failed on vserver247.axc.nl: error 126 "sh: /usr/local/bin/: Is a directory" from "'/usr/local/bin/' '-quality' '80' '-background' 'white' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/public_html/naslag/images/7/74/Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '-thumbnail' '358x599!' '-set' 'comment' 'File source: http://aanbevolen.nu/naslag/index.php/File:Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '+set' 'Thumb::URI' '-depth' '8' '-sharpen' '0x0.4' '-rotate' '-0' '-sampling-factor' '2x2,1x1,1x1' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_a040c6429df4.jpg'"
[thumbnail] Removing bad 0-byte thumbnail "/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_a040c6429df4.jpg". unlink() succeeded
[thumbnail] thumbnail failed on vserver247.axc.nl: error 126 "sh: /usr/local/bin/: Is a directory" from "'/usr/local/bin/' '-quality' '80' '-background' 'white' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/public_html/naslag/images/7/74/Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '-thumbnail' '72x120!' '-set' 'comment' 'File source: http://aanbevolen.nu/naslag/index.php/File:Delano_Hutjens.jpg' '+set' 'Thumb::URI' '-depth' '8' '-sharpen' '0x0.4' '-rotate' '-0' '-sampling-factor' '2x2,1x1,1x1' '/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_dac4b137ee51.jpg'"
[thumbnail] Removing bad 0-byte thumbnail "/home/dickihs247/domains/aanbevolen.nu/mediawiki_tmp/transform_dac4b137ee51.jpg". unlink() succeeded
```

Comment: I suggest you show your code. From the error it looks like the input file is a directory and not an image file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Underneath you see the complete code:
I did chance some name and ip adres but the important things are not changed.
I hope you can help me. Thanks:

see: http://aanbevolen.nu/error%20126.txt

Comment: You must define `$wgImageMagickConvertCommand` including the binary name. See the [Manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgImageMagickConvertCommand).

Comment: Thanks diving into it.
I got this reaction from prompt:

[dicki****@v***** ~]$ which -a convert
/usr/bin/which: no convert in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/dicki*****/.local/bin:/home/dicki*****/bin)

So there is no Convert :-) I asked my Hosting compagny.

To be continued